# Ui-State not showing in Ui

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I have these 2 ui states: **productHomeUiState**(that keeps track of the actual entities), and **filterProductUiState**(that keeps track of the filtered entities).

My problem is, no matter how i call the Room-query that filters the Entities(Products), the **filteredProductList** in **filterProductUiState**, is always empty, therefore there are no results in the UI (Lazycolumn), not showing the filtered Entities, that match the criteria of the Query.
I can't find the issue, that's causing **filterProductUiState** not to work.

I tried fixing it, but nothing worked.

**Viewmodel:**

```
class ProductViewModel(productRepository: ProductRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val productHomeUiState: StateFlow<ProductHomeUiState> =
        productRepository.getAllProductsStream().map { ProductHomeUiState(it) }
            .stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(TIMEOUT_MILLIS),
                initialValue = ProductHomeUiState()
            )

    companion object {
        private const val TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 5_000L
    }

    private var isFilterActive = false

    fun isFilterActive(): Boolean {
        return isFilterActive
    }

    private var category: List<Category?> = emptyList()
    private var currency: String = ""
    private var startPrice: Double = 0.0
    private var endPrice: Double = 0.0
    private var startDate: String = ""
    private var endDate: String = ""
    private var company: String = ""

    private var categoryStrings: List<String> = emptyList()

    fun applyProductFilter(
        category: List<Category?>,
        currency: String,
        startPrice: Double,
        endPrice: Double,
        startDate: String,
        endDate: String,
        company: String
    ) {
        isFilterActive = true

        this.category = category
        this.currency = currency
        this.startPrice = startPrice
        this.endPrice = endPrice
        this.startDate = startDate
        this.endDate = endDate
        this.company = company


        val stringValues: List<String> = category
            .mapNotNull { it?.value }

        this.categoryStrings = stringValues

        Log.d("Core category", "Category=${stringValues}")
    }


    val filteredProductUiState: StateFlow<FilterProductUiState> =
        productRepository.filterCategory(categoryStrings)
            .map { FilterProductUiState(it) }
            .stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(TIMEOUT_MILLIS),
                initialValue = FilterProductUiState(),
            )
}

    data class ProductHomeUiState(
        val productList: List<Product> = listOf()
    )

    data class FilterProductUiState(
        val filterProductList: List<Product> = listOf()
    )
```

**Query:**
*Dao:*

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE category IN (:categoryList)")
    fun filterByCategory(categoryList: List<String>): Flow<List<Product>>
```

*Repo:*

```
fun filterCategory(category: List<String>):  Flow<List<Product>>
```

*Offline-Repo:*

```
override fun filterCategory(category: List<String>):  Flow<List<Product>> = productDao.filterByCategory(category)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `productRepository.filterCategory(categoryStrings)` is only called once when your `ProductViewModel` is created and at that time `categoryStrings` is an empty list. You have to do a new call to `filterCategory` when the filter parameters change. That can be done for example with another flow:

```
data class FilterParams(
    val categoryStrings: List<String> = emptyList(),
    val currency: String = "",
    ...
)

private val filterFlow = MutableStateFlow(FilterParams())

fun applyProductFilter(
    category: List<Category?>,
    currency: String,
) { filterFlow.value = FilterParams(...) }

val filteredProductUiState = filterFlow.flatMapLatest { filterParams ->
    productRepository.filterCategory(filterParams.categoryStrings)
}.map { FilterProductUiState(it) }.stateIn(...)
```

Here, every time you set new value to `filterFlow` (in applyProductFilter), `productRepository.filterCategory` will be called with that new new value thanks to `flatMapLatest`.